# mySQL UPDATE failed. What is wrong with this mySQL UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql

here's the generated query:

```
   UPDATE namelist
SET 'submitterName' = 'Jim'
    ,'actorName' = 'dingle'
    ,'setYear' = '1103'
    ,'country' = 'tanata'
    ,'blink' = 'on'
    ,'crush' = 'on'
    ,'initialize' = 'on'
    ,'entered' = 'on'
    ,'stuck' = 'on'
    ,'catapult' = 'on'
    ,'ruck' = 'on'
WHERE id = 31
```

it generates this (less than helpful) error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near (query snippet) at line 1

for the life of me, i can't spot where the problem is.  yes, column names match, yes

TIA for helping out.

WR!

Comment: i've read ALL of the related 'mySQL UPDATE' posts and found nothin illuminating.  AFAIK, this query is sound!  :P

Comment: You have used single quotes for columns, replace it with backquote

Comment: the error is less helpful for us when you replace where it says the error is with *"(query snippet)"*. you'd be supprised how many times this gives you a great hint of where to start looking

Comment: Yes, as one of the above comment says it, either replace the single quote you have used for column names with backquote, or remove the single quote. Also check if your setYear is a string or integer and use quotes accordingly.

Comment: Memor-X:  it's literally a snippet.  it's just the first 50 chars of the query.  thanks for the pointer though.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used single quotes before and after columns in the query, replace those single quotes with backquotes.

So the query like

```
UPDATE  namelist 
SET     `submitterName`='Jim', 
        `actorName`='dingle', 
        `setYear`='1103', 
        `country`='tanata', 
        `blink`='on', 
        `crush`='on', 
        `initialize`='on', 
        `entered`='on', 
        `stuck`='on', 
        `catapult`='on', 
        `ruck`='on' 
WHERE   id=31;
```

Comment: yup.  that's the bunny.  thanks.  i admit, it never crossed my mind to use those.  would it work with double quotes?  if so, that's probably why...i've heretofore used doubles.  but got bit using them for everything in PHP, so switched to singles.  at any rate: very much thank you!  :D

Answer (score 0):

user `  instead of '

like this

```
UPDATE namelist SET `submitterName`='Jim',`actorName`='dingle',`setYear`='1103',`country`='tanata',`blink`='on',`crush`='on',`initialize`='on',`entered`='on',`stuck`='on',`catapult`='on',`ruck`='on' WHERE id=31
```